# How can I make javac and java aware of my downloaded API?

Tags: java, pdfbox

> Note : I am unfamiliar with working at the command line, and my naive question will
>   most likely prompt a simple answer.  With that in mind, read on :)

I downloaded the Apache PDFBox API into `/c/Users/mount/Java/bin/pdfbox-2.0.3`.  My program files are unable to locate the contents of this API ( despite accurate import statements ).

**How can I make `javac` and `java` aware of my downloaded Java API?**

Below are my current settings for the commands and PATH.

```
PATH=$PATH:/c/Users/mount/Java/bin
alias javac="javac -cp /c/Users/mount/Java/JavaFX/jsoup_api:."
alias java="java -cp /c/Users/mount/Java/JavaFX/jsoup_api:/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_101/lib:."
```

I have attempted to solve my problem by adding `/c/Users/mount/Java/bin/pdfbox-2.0.3` to the end to each of these alias statements, however, that has not been successful.  My Java program files are located in sub directories under /Java.

Comment: You should use Maven or another package manager instead of downloading APIs by hand.

Comment: Libraries are usually packaged as jar files, and I don't see any in your classpath.

Comment: You need to specify the jar files explicitly, meaning the whole filename including the `.jar` extension, or a wildcard on the folder  `.../jsoup_api/*`. This could also be a cygwin issue. Try doing this in the default system console

Answer (score 1):

Your classpath should be set like this:

```
javac -cp lib/bar.jar com/example/Foo.java
```

So, only the full path to .jar (including the filename with extension!) is missing.

For exemple, the javac version should be like this:

```
alias javac="javac -cp /c/Users/mount/Java/JavaFX/jsoup_api:/c/Users/mount/Java/bin/pdfbox-2.0.3/pdfbox-app-2.0.3.jar:."
```

Just make sure that the .jar file exists!

Comment: Hmmm.  I have applied your suggestions and my problem remains.  Thank you for the support, though!

Comment: Are you using cygwin? Try typing this: ls /c/Users/mount/Java/bin/pdfbox-2.0.3/